# How do I create a dictionary object for passing to Zstd.compress?

Tags: java, dictionary, compression, zstd

I am using Zstd compression in Java for compressing a large JSON payload. I am using methods from the zstd-jni library for Java. I create a byte array out of the JSON string and use this method.

public static byte[] compress(byte[] var0, int var1)

I read that ZSTD will give more optimal results when a dictionary is passed during compression and decompression. How do I create a ZstdDictCompress object? What byte array and integer should I pass to the constructor?

public static long compress(byte[] var0, byte[] var1, ZstdDictCompress var2)

Comment: I guess you are talking about training-based dicts [zstd docs](http://facebook.github.io/zstd/#small-data). Using zstds tools, some binary-dict will be generated through some training procedure and i'm pretty optimistic that your func-signature exactly want's those raw bytes. Howewer: This makes things much more complex: training-data acquisition, training-procedure, making sure compressor/decompressor use the same version of the pre-trained dict. It also is designed to help for small-data cases (you say: `large JSON payload`). With big data, this should not help. Maybe just tune the compr-lvl

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm looking for something to help with reducing decompression speeds for large JSON payloads (I'm happy with the compression ratio without the dict). If the large JSON payload has a lot of repeated patterns, will the dictionary help? Or is it only useful for smaller payloads as the documentation suggests? I can't change the compr-lvl for my situation unfortunately

Answer (score 9):

This example is for https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni.

First of all you need to get many samples of your jsons. You shouldn't use just one or couple samples. After that you can train your dictionary:

```java
List<String> jsons = ...; // List of your jsons samples

ZstdDictTrainer trainer = new ZstdDictTrainer(1024 * 1024, 16 * 1024); // 16 KB dictionary

for(String json : jsons) {
    trainer.addSample(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}

byte[] dictionary = trainer.trainSamples();
```

Now you have you dictionary in byte array.

Next step is using **SAME** dictionary to compress and decompress.

```java
// Compress
byte[] json = jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
ZstdDictCompress zstdDictCompress = new ZstdDictCompress(dictionary, Zstd.defaultCompressionLevel());
byte[] compressed = Zstd.compress(json, zstdDictCompress);

// Tricky moment, you have to pass json full length to decompress method
int jsonFullLength = json.length;

// Decompress
ZstdDictDecompress zstdDictDecompress = new ZstdDictDecompress(dictionary);
byte[] decompressed = Zstd.decompress(compressed, zstdDictDecompress, jsonFullLength);
String jsonString2 = new String(decompressed, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

That's all!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't find sample code for this anywhere. Appreciate it!